# Python program, list not printing

Tags: python, list, palindrome

I have the following program which seeks to check the similarity between two lists. However, the originalword (list) prints correctly the first time but not the second therefore the code doesn't work to check equivalence.

https://trinket.io/python3/b3b7827717

Can anyone spot the error? If so, could a solution be posted
a) using lists
b) Not introducing any new skills (e.g. string slicing)

```
def palindromechecker():
  print("----Palindrome Checker---")
  
  word=input("Enter word:")
  
  #empty list for reversed word
  originalword=[]
  reversedword=[]
  
  #put each letter in word in the list originallist
  for i in range(len(word)):
    originalword.append(word[i])
  print("Print original word in order:",originalword)
  
  #reverse the word
  for i in range(len(word)):
    reversedword.append(originalword.pop()) 
  print("Reversed word:",reversedword)
  print("Original word:",originalword)
  
  #are original word and reversed word the same?
  
  if originalword==reversedword:
    print("--Palindrome Found--")
  else:
    print("--Not a Palindrome---")

palindromechecker()
```

Comment: You're adding to `reversedword` in the same order you're iterating through `originalword`. In other words, you're not iterating in the right direction. Have you tried doing `for i in range(len(word) - 1, 0, -1):` instead for the second loop?

Comment: No, note that it works fine the first time and prints the reversedword list and original list correctly. e.g. apple and elppa    and eve and eve.

Comment: Feel free to post a solution if you have one..

Comment: `.pop()` removes the item, so `originalword` ends up as an empty list.

Comment: I could do it like this, but seems terribly inefficient to have three lists. https://trinket.io/python3/3763f2ac60

Comment: May i ask why not just comparing originalwords == originalwords[::-1]?

Answer (score 1):

You make *originalword* list empty by doing that `originalword.pop()` in the second loop. Better way to do that is just reverse list like that

`reversedword = originalword[::-1]`

It will work without loop

Or you can do something like that:

```py
for i in range(len(word)):
    reversedword.append(originalword[-1-i])
```

Comment: You don't even need the lists.  `if word == word[::-1]`

Comment: i want, for demo purposes, to do it with lists. Looking for the most efficient way without introducing something new - e.g. ::-1

Comment: see updated question. I want a solution that a) uses lists b) does not introduce any new methods or concepts e.g. string slicing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.pop()` method, it will update the existing list by removing the last element from the list. So it is exhausting your `originalword` list.

I read that you don't want to use `string[::-1]`. Here is a similar but not the same workaround. You have to run the loop in reverse.

```
  #reverse the word
  for i in range(len(word)-1, -1, -1):
    reversedword.append(originalword[i])
```